# How to transform JSON field name to match Fullcalendar object in Angular (angular ui-calendar)?

Tags: json, angularjs, fullcalendar

I am using the Angular [ui-calendar](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-calendar/), which is an Angular version of the [Arshaw FullCalendar](http://fullcalendar.io/). My problem is that the calendar itself requires a "title" field, while I have to use a predefined model for appointments, which does not have such a field. The empty JSON model looks like this:

```
"Appointment": {
            "resourceType": "Appointment",
            "identifier": [],
            "status": {},
            "type": {},
            "reason": "",
            "priority": {},
            "description": "",
            "start": "",
            "end": "",
            "minutesDuration": "",
            "slot": [],
            "comment": "",
            "participant": [{
                    "type": [],
                    "actor": [],
                    "required": [],
                    "status": []
                }] //End of "Appointment"
        }
```

I am trying to transform the "description" field name into a "title" in my calendar options. Currently, without the `eventDataTransform`, the basic configuration is this:

```
calendarController.calendarOptions = {
                    calendar: {
                        lang: 'bg',
                        height: 450,
                        editable: true,
                        selectable: true,
                        events: calendarController.searchSet,
                        dataType: "json",
                        eventColor: '#30ACFF',
                        header: {
                            right: 'month agendaWeek agendaDay today prev,next'
                        },
                        timeFormat: 'H(:mm)'
                    }

                };
```

I've found an [example](https://gist.github.com/mvark/92478ce44c3ddde0b100) of field name transformation on GitHub gist, however it is not the AngularJS compliant configuration and I am not using ajax calls in my app, I'm using a service to fetch data from the server:

```
calendarController.searchSet = CalendarService.search({type: 'Appointment'});
```

Hence, it doesn't work for an Angular app and the Angular Docs for ui-calendar configuration are almost non-existent. So basically, I get an event that shows up in the calendar but has no title. What is the right way to configure event field name transformation if you are using Fullcalendar with Angular and a RESTful service to get data and populate the calendar with the correct field names, without modifying the predefined model for the appointment?